# How to fetch first_name,email,user_type from two table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to fetch first_name,email,user_type from two table?

```
table 1 ( recruiter_master )
      1)recruiter_id
      2)first_name
      3)email
      4)password
      5)user_type

    table 2 ( freelancer_master )
       1)freelancer_id
       2)first_name
       3)email
       4)password
       5)user_type
```

I want to fetch recruiter_id/freelancer_id, first_name and email, user_type.
if email and password match return data of related table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `recruiter_master`,   `freelancer_master`
WHERE  (recruiter_master.email="abc@gmail.com" AND 
        recruiter_master.password="abc123") OR 
       (freelancer_master.email="abc@gmail.com" AND 
        freelancer_master.password="abc123")
```

it return both table data.

Answer (score 0):

What you Need is a `Union`

```
SELECT * FROM `recruiter_master` WHERE  recruiter_master.email="abc@gmail.com" AND recruiter_master.password="abc123"
UNION
select * from `freelancer_master` where (freelancer_master.email="abc@gmail.com" AND freelancer_master.password="abc123")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
recruiter_id,
freelancer_id,
recruiter_master.first_name,
recruiter_master.email,
recruiter_master.user_type
FROM recruiter_master
INNER JOIN freelancer_master 
ON recruiter_master.email = freelancer_master.email
AND recruiter_master.password = freelancer_master.password
WHERE  (recruiter_master.email="abc@gmail.com" AND recruiter_master.password="abc123")
```

Do you want:

```
recruiter_master.first_name,
recruiter_master.email,
recruiter_master.user_type
```

or:

```
freelancer_master.first_name,
freelancer_master.email,
freelancer_master.user_type
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for reply.I want to pass value of email and password